# How do i select all rows that meet the value for a specific column in a specific row

Tags: vba

I am writing a code that will do something like this:
With the active cell selected, I want to select other rows in the table that match the value for the active Row in column D. example, if the for the active row has a value of "Sea" in column D, I want to loop through all the rows and selected those that have "sea" in column D.

An SQL equivalent of what I am looking for is this:

```
SELECT * From Table1 
Where columnD=(Select ColumnD From Table1 Where ColumnA=ActiveCell)
```

Comment: You can use the [Worksheet_SelectionChange event.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheet-selectionchange-event-excel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've revised the code to now do what you've asked. The animated gif shows it tested for 3 cases.

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Sub test3()
Dim tableR As Range, cell As Range, r As Range
Dim s As String
Set tableR = Range("A1:C10")
Set r = Selection
For Each cell In tableR
  If cell = r Then
  s = s & cell.Row & ":" & cell.Row & ", "
  End If
Next cell
s = Left(s, Len(s) - 2)
Range(s).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Close to the gif but, I want to select the entire rows. let say  if the active cell is C1 which has a value of Lake, I want to select all rows that have the value of the active  cell. So In this case, Rows 1,4, and 8 will be selected.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, i really appreciate the time.